# I've got "The object's state must be OPENED."

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've tried to perform AJAX request, but I've got this kind of error, that ajax call should be opened. But it is opened already. Trying to send the XMLHttpRequest header, but getting this kinda error. Guys, help me!

````
let del_btn = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
for(let i = 0; i < del_btn.length; i++)
{
del_btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let book_title = del_btn[i].parentElement.children[1].children[1].children[0].children[0].textContent;
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            {
                if(this.responseText.includes('Deleted'))
                {
                    let books = this.responseText.split('.')[1];
                    if(books == '0')
                    {
                        del_btn[i].parentElement.parentElement.innerHTML = 'You have no books in your list. Go to the ' + ' ' + '<a href="index.php"> main page </a>' + ' ' + 'and start your ride!';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        del_btn[i].parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(del_btn[i].parentElement);
                        document.querySelector('.amount-b').textContent = 'Количество книг: ' + books;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        xhr.open("POST", "../operations/delete_book.php", true);
        xml.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send('title=' + book_title);
    }, false);
}```
````

Comment: `xml.setRequestHeader`  Looks like a typo there

Comment: @PatrickQ ahahahah, you're the best, I was starting to think about my life...